# How to find the mime type of .bat file using Tika API?

Tags: java, spring, apache-tika

I am using `tika-core.jar` to detect the mime type.

When I try to find the mime type of bat file, it is giving mime type as `text/plain` instead of `application/x-bat`.

Comment: probably you should update tika (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2445 - resolved:1.17), or file a new issue.

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? If not the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Answer (score 3):

Tika is giving the correct output.

The jar used is `tika-core-1.22`.

**The code is given below (what I have tried) :**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File batchFile = new File("C:/Users/Anish/Desktop/abc.bat");
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        System.out.println(tika.detect(batchFile));
    }

}
```

**Screenshot of the output :**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

still am getting text/plain for bat file. I don't understand why  i am getting text/plain
[image: i did test the code in my local but am getting text/plain for bat file]

Comment: package tika;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;
public class T4{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
File f = new File("bld.bat");
Tika tik = new Tika()
String mime = tik.detect(f);
System.out.println(mime);

Comment: @Vinod Can you share what is written in the batch file ?

Comment: if "%ARCH%"=="32" (
set PLATFORM=x86
) else (
set PLATFORM=x64
)

:: build the shell
cl shell.c sqlite3.c -Fesqlite3.exe /DSQLITE_EXPORTS

:: build the dll
cl sqlite3.c -link -dll -out:sqlite3.dll

COPY sqlite3.exe %LIBRARY_BIN%\
COPY sqlite3.dll %LIBRARY_BIN%\
COPY sqlite3.lib %LIBRARY_LIB%\
COPY sqlite3.h   %LIBRARY_INC%\

Comment: @Vinod One thing you can do. I guess the problem is with the batch file. The solution I gave try that. create a demo bat file containing nothing. and just pass that and check the mime type. If it shows the application/x-bat, then it's ok. Then, the script that you wrote in bld.bat. Just copy and paste into the demo bat file. Then try to check mime type. If it's not showing application/x-bat,then the script is having some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Note: in the case of *.bat files, Tika (1.24.1) relies only on the .bat extension only, it does not parse the content. And just noticed that's not even alway true. It does not spot *.ps1 even with the extension. In both cases it returns text/plain